combine Stochastic RSI and MacD strategy
I would like to create an indicator to use on tradingview combining Stochastic RSI and MacD Strategy so that I am only opening 1 indicator instead of 2. I dont know anything about coding and have never done anything like this before. I have the code for both indicators I just dont know how to combine them, and if it can be done. Is there anyone here that i able to help me with this?
Macd Strategy
+
Generic Stochastic RSI code
i keep getting an error code that i don't understand. and I'm hoping someone can just combine the 2 codes into 1
